# Releasing a C type declared as an Objective-C property

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management

I have declared a C type as a property of my Objective-C object.  I would like to make sure that my property is getting garbage collected properly by ARC.

Just iterating a bunch of times doesn't leak memory, but since I haven't found proper documentation on the subject I would like to confirm.

Basically, when I override `dealloc` to free my C type, I get an error my variable was never allocated:

> malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated ***
>   set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property (readonly, assign) xmlDocPtr doc;
@end

@implementation MyClass
    - (void)dealloc {
       if (_doc != NULL) {
          xmlFreeDoc(_doc);  // throwing da runtime error, see above!
       }
       NSLog(@"dealloc'ed!"); // call me please T___T
    }

    // Setting my C-type property here:
    - (instancetype)initWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path {
       NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
       [self setDoc:htmlReadMemory([data bytes], (int)[data length], "", NULL, HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR)];

       if (_doc == NULL) return nil;

       NSLog(@"init'ed!");  // gets called!
       return self;
    }

    // Property setter (as suggested by DarkDust):
    - (void)setDoc:(xmlDocPtr)doc {
       if (_doc != NULL) xmlFreeDoc(_doc);
       _doc = doc;
    }
@end
```

Comment: I think you mean `if (_doc != NULL) xmlFreeDoc(_doc);` without the `&`. If that doesn't fix item please update your question sharing what compiler error you are receiving.

Comment: @Rob edited my super awesome-looking post!

Comment: This revised sample looks fine to me. It runs without error for me. Are you sure you might not have a `xmlFreeDoc` lingering about elsewhere?

Comment: @Rob nope, the entire lifecycle of that pointer is there.

Comment: OK. Without [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm unable to advise further. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since ARC can only operate on Objective-C objects, it cannot help you with managing C types.

A vital question to correctly managing memory always is *"who 'owns' the object?"* In Objective-C, that's done using reference counting and clear naming rules to aid that. Since you don't have that with the C types, you need to be careful.

So, who is creating your `xmlDoc` instance? If it's the same object for which you've written the `dealloc` method (let's call that class `Foo`), and you just want to expose the instance via the property, the ownership is clear: `Foo` is the owner of instance and thus needs to clean it up. You're already doing that in `dealloc` in this case (though you have a bug there; the variable itself *always* has an address, so `&_doc` will never be NULL!). I would make the property *read-only* to avoid anyone messing with the pointer from the outside (to assign it, you'd then need to access the backing variable `_doc` directly). It would thus look like this:

```
@property(readonly, assign) xmlDocPtr doc;

...
_doc = CreateTheXMLDocInstance();
...

- (void)dealloc {
    if (_doc != NULL) xmlFreeDoc(_doc);
}
```

If you actually want to make the property writable, you need to correctly handle the setter. Again, the question is: who owns the instance? If you want the `Foo` object to be the sole owner, things are actually pretty easy. You'll just need to write a custom setter to deallocate old instances:

```
- (void)setDoc:(xmlDocPtr)doc {
    // Do not free if it's the same pointer.
    if (doc == _doc) return;
    // Remove old instance, if we have one.
    if (_doc != NULL) xmlFreeDoc(_doc);
    // Assign new instance.
    _doc = doc;
}
```

If the `Foo` object would not be the sole owner it would not be allowed to deallocate `_doc` in the setter nor in `dealloc`.

Comment: I've added more code for you to look at.  Basically still running into same issue...  The reason I placed the `&` was to troubleshoot.  I removed it and added the `readonly` and `assign` directives too.  The creator of the C type is the object itself.  I don't think it matters that it just happens to be inside an initialization method.  The owner is still the property owning class, I presume.

Comment: the setter implementation is wrong.  you are not taking ownership there so you should not free there either. Also invalid when doc == _doc.

Comment: @Sulthan I am implementing the setter like DarkDust suggested and it still raises the same error.  Editing post to reflect that.  Besides, how can the C type owner be different from the object itself if it is declared as a property and set inside that object?

Comment: @Sulthan: Good point about `doc == _doc` (fixed the setter), but what do you mean with _"you are not taking ownership"_? This is how the setter should look like exactly _if_ the object should become the new, sole owner of the `xmlDocPtr`.

Answer (score 0):

Now for your runtime error you've cited after updating the question: the error message tells you that someone is trying to free an address that was not the return value of `malloc`. Most likely, the value assigned to `_doc` is not valid pointer, or at least not a pointer to the beginning of a block of memory that was returned by `malloc`. That in turn means the error must be somewhere in your `htmlReadMemory` function: it doesn't return a valid `xmlDocPtr`.

Comment: I'm able to access members of the returned xmlDocPtr though.